# Creating a System.Func without specifying the generic argument

Tags: c#

I have the following piece of code I use in my tests which has a bit of duplication:

```
Func<string, User> getUser = GetFirstItem<User>;

Func<string, Plan> getPlan = GetFirstItem<Plan>;

_planLeader = UserRoleHelper.GetUserWithAdditionalPlans(_commonDao, getUser, getPlan, 5);
```

The GetFirstItem method has the following signature:

```
 T GetFirstItem<T>(string whereClause) where T : class
```

My problem is that I am having to create two separate variables getUser and GetPlan for the 2 different function calls in order to explicitly declare the generic argument.

Is it possible to create a System.Func without declaring the generic type?

Something like:

```
Func<T, User> getUser = GetFirstItem<T>;
```

This obviously will not compile as T is not defined.

Is there a way round this?

Comment: Why would you want to put them into the same variable?

Answer (score 1):

Would it make sense to do this:

```
_planLeader = UserRoleHelper.GetUserWithAdditionalPlans(
    _commonDao,
    GetFirstItem<User>,
    GetFirstItem<Plan>,
    5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a doubly generic method?

```
Func<string, User> userDelegate = GetFirstItem<string, User>("Hello World");
Func<int, User> userDelegate2 = GetFirstItem<int, User>("Hello World2");
```

Where your generic method is like so:

```
public Func<T, U> GetFirstItem<T, U>(string whereClause)
     where T: class
     where U: class
{
   // Logic
}
```

Of course, without knowing exactly what logic you are trying to do, this question is a bit harder to answer.